# grep in Bash script - "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to output the first line of a text file containing the first argument, and then output the first line of a text file containing the second argument.

When using only 1 argument in the shell, the following code works:

Sample run: bash tester.sh first

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -m 1 $1 list.txt
```

However, this code does not work when trying to use 2 arguments:

Sample run: bash tester.sh first second

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -m 1 $1 list.txt
grep -m 1 $2 list.txt
```

The second script produces an error stating "No such file or directory" but then it will output the result of the **second** grep. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: post the full error message (preceding `"No such file or directory"`)

Comment: I suggest to test with `bash -x tester.sh first second`.

Comment: Check your file for special characters with `cat -A tester.sh` or `cat -v tester.sh`.

Comment: When I test using bash -x, the result is:
+ grep -m 1 first $'list.txt\r'
: No such file or directory
+ grep -m 1 second list.txt
this line contains the word second

Comment: I suggest to get rid of `\r` with `dos2unix  tester.sh`.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus that worked great! I couldn't get rid of the \r no matter what I did